# Split text on some, but not all spaces

Tags: php, regex, text, split, cpu-word

I am working on a php project for cooking recipes and am stuck a bit of finding a decent way to split every ingredient from a text area box using PHP.

Here is an example of ingredient lines:

```
100 grams almonds (preferrably raw) or 1 egg
```

The text above should be split as follows:

```
100,
grams,
almonds (preferrably raw) && 1,
egg
```

Bear in mind, that some lines have just two words (spaces) but some would have more. I tried to split the words before the space into an array, however on lines with two words I am getting an error: Undefined offset...

Comment: This pattern seems random but look in to `explode` and BTW, that doesn't seem like every space rather a fixed interval depending on the following words.

Comment: Well the pattern I am needing is to grab the first word which would always be the quantity. Then grab the second one which would be the measurement (in the case of line 1) or the ingredient in the case of line two. My thinking is that I might need to check how many spaces there are per line. If three, than the split would go:

$quantity $measurement $ingredient

In the case the spaces are two, the split would be:
$quantity, $ingredient
** Script47 ** You are right, the spaces could be more or less, so I am thinking more on grabbing the whole text split by space and assign it to a var

Comment: You'll probably need a rather complex RegEx, I think.

Comment: My logical way of thinking is the following:

1. As far as the ingredients list is a multiple lines text assigned to variable $recipe_ingredients, I would have to clear any empty lines showing between ingredients:

$str = implode("\n", array_filter(explode("\n", $recipe_ingredients)));

Then I will have to split the text into lines assigning the result to $text variable:

$text = explode( "\n", $str );

Then to make sure there are no extra spaces in the ingredient line,I will have to strip any multiple spaces:

$ingr = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $text));

Comment: Then I would think to count the number of words in $text and if the words are more than two, than the ingredient structure would be considered as: quantity, measure, ingredient. If the count shows only two words, than the ingredient structure would be: quantity, ingredient.

Now what I do not know how to achieve is to read all words into an array and then assign the variables to every one depending on the ingredient structure...

Comment: would you share the final solution?

Answer (score 0):

Match words starting composed of `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, then optionally continue matching for your specified occurrences. If you come to realise there are more trailing substrings to cover, just add to the non-capturing group. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/UaVHh)

```
$string = '100 grams almonds (preferrably raw) && 1 egg';

var_export(
    preg_match_all(
        '/\w+(?: && \d+| \([^)]+\))*/',
        $string,
        $m
    )
    ? $m[0]
    : []
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '100',
  1 => 'grams',
  2 => 'almonds (preferrably raw) && 1',
  3 => 'egg',
)
```